# Does Cling Android support HLS (HTTP live streaming)?

Tags: android, upnp, dlna, android-cling

In other words, instead of picking a media file from a mobile device, can it accept a live stream url and play the video on TV from that url?

I could not find anything related to this in Cling Core User Manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your online video urls in a .m3u8 file and then put this file in your Digital Media Server (DMS) folder. Then DLNA player can play the links inside this file. But not all DLNA Digital Media Players (DMP) support this format.

Comment: can you give some info about creating a DMS ?